# Чистить поля input после ввода?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите как правильно очищать мои посля после нажатия кнопки "Add"

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
   return {
    topic: '',
    checked: true,
    personTask: '',
    arrs: [],
    tasks: []

   }
  },
  methods: {
   addTask() {
    this.tasks.push(this.personTask, this.checked)  
   },
   submitHandler() { 
    this.arrs.push(this.topic, this.tasks)
   },
   // 
  }

 })
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <div> 
    <input type="text" id="checked" value="" v-model="topic">
    <div >
     <input type="checkbox" id="checked" value="" v-model="checked">
    <input v-model="personTask" type="text" id="personTask" >
    </div>
    <button @click="addTask">have tasks</button>

  <hr>
    <button @click="submitHandler">Add </button>
   </div>
   
   <div v-for="arr of arrs" class="task">
    {{arr}}
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант создать функцию:

```
setDefaultValues(){
  this.personTask = '';
  this.checked = true; // или какое тут дефолтное значение
}
```

И везде где надо сбрасывать значения - вызывать эту функцию. Например в `addTask`.

Если появляется новое значение - дописывать в одном месте в функцию `setDefaultValues` его "сброс"

Comment: чистить массив после создания, а то у меня после создания новой заметки опять то же задания стоит при создания новой

Comment: this.tasks = [];